# I wish or I do wish

Tags: do-support, wish

I don’t understand, what is the difference in meaning  between:

> - I wish
> - I do wish ?

Does the use of “do” make the wish stronger?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. *Do* is acting as an intensifier:

- I wish you would shut up.
- I **do** wish you would shut up.

Apart from providing emphasis, the meaning is the same.

> I **do** like a bit of Gorgonzola.

Nick Parkes, *The Wrong Trousers* (1993) (Wallace and Gromit)